Calling nonvirtual Derived::memFun via (pBase->*baseMemPtr)() : is it legal?
Pointer to member function of derived class can be converted to pointer to member of base B via static_cast. A note in [expr.static.cast] of c++20 draft says

[Note: Although class B need not contain the original member, the
dynamic type of the object with which indirection through the pointer
to member is performed must contain the original member; see 7.6.4. —
end note]

Here is the related part of 7.6.4:

Abbreviating pm-expression.*cast-expression as E1.*E2, E1 is called
the object expression. If the dynamic type of E1 does not contain the
member to which E2 refers, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, the
expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2.

Since both points seems to imply that only the dynamic type of object matters, I was hoping that it is legal to call such a pointer-to-nonvirtual-member-function on a pointer to base class suboject of derived object. In gcc, clang, and mingw this indeed seems to be the case, at least in the code that I used for testing (see below). However, it doesn't work in msvc (my asserts fire).
But if such a call is illegal, then what is the point in emphasizing the "dynamic type" of E1?
BTW, slightly different wording can be found on cppreference, see text starting with Conversion in the opposite direction, from a pointer to member function and example that follows. But it that example they invoke pointer-to-member-of-base on derived class object, what does not explain the significance of "dynamic type" of E1. Nonetheless, asserts in msvc do not fire when the static type of E1 is the derived class itself.
Here is the code I used for testing:
#include<cassert>
#include<type_traits>

struct B{

};

struct A1{
   int arr[8];
};

struct A2{
   long double arr[8];
};


struct D1 : A1, B {
   int md1 = 13;
   int f1()  const {  return md1; }
};

struct D2 : A2, B {
   int md2 = 2;
   int f2()  const {  return md2; }
};


int main()
{
       D1 d1;
       D2 d2;
       
       B *pb1 = &d1,
         *pb2 = &d2;
       
       auto pmf1 = static_cast<int (B::*)() const>(&D1::f1);
       auto pmf2 = static_cast<int (B::*)() const>(&D2::f2);
       
       assert( (pb1->*pmf1)()==13 ); //fires in msvc
       assert( (pb2->*pmf2)()==2 ); // fires in msvc
       
 } 


It's actually a multiple-inheritance problem. but it looks misguided by MSVC. It should be relevant to arr in A1 not to f1 in D1, but apparently their compler can generate incorrect code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4407?view=msvc-170

Can even be tested with constexpr (which check for most UB) Demo

/vmg fixes it: https://godbolt.org/z/xaTh464jc as does rearranging your base class order: https://godbolt.org/z/vjejEqdTj
